# C++ - Macro defines directive

Tags: c++, macros

At: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/110-a-first-look-at-the-preprocessor/

It mentions a directive called "**Macro defines**". What do we mean when we say "**Macro**"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A macro is a code fragment that gets substituted into your program by the preprocessor (before compilation proper begins).  This may be a function-like block, or it may be a constant value.

A warning when using a function-like macro.  Consider the following code:

```
#define foo(x) x*x
```

If you call `foo(3)`, it will become (and be compiled as) `3*3` (=9).  If, instead, you call `foo(2+3)`, it will become `2+3*2+3`, (=2+6+3=11), which is not what you want.  Also, since the code is substituted in place, `foo(bar++)` becomes `bar++ * bar++`, incrementing `bar` twice.

Macros are powerful tools, but it can be easy to shoot yourself in the foot while trying to do something fancy with them.

Comment: `bar++ * bar++` may or may not increment `bar` twice. It is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

A macro is a preprocessor directive that defines a name that is to be replaced (or removed) by the preprocessor right before compilation.

Example:

```
#define MY_MACRO1 somevalue
#define MY_MACRO2
#define SUM(a, b) (a + b)
```

then if anywhere in the code (except in the string literals) there is a mention of `MY_MACRO1` or `MY_MACRO2` the preprocessor replaces this with whatever comes after the name in the `#define` line.

There can also be macros with parameters (like the SUM). In that case the preprocessor recognizes the arguments, example:

```
int x = 1, y = 2;
int z = SUM(x, y);
```

preprocessor replaces like this:

```
int x = 1, y = 2;
int z = (x + y);
```

only after this replacement the compiler gets to compile the resulting code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding "#define SUM(a, b) (a + b)", should we include a+b between parantheses always? Thanks.

Comment: @SWEngineer It would work without parentheses in this case, but consider this code: `int z = SUM(a, b) * 3;` If SUM was defined without parentheses this would expand to `int z = a + b * 3;`, thats probably not what you want.

Comment: @SWEngineer Also I should mention that if you plan on passing more complicated expressions as arguments to the SUM, you should always keep in mind that SUM is not a function and sideefects could work differently from a function. Generally to minimize possible bugs, use as much parentheses as possible. Consider this: `#define MULT(a, b) (a * b)` and you use it like this: `m = MULT(a + b, 10);` this again expands counterintuitively into `m = (a + b * 10);`. A correct deffinition for MULT would be `#define MULT(a, b) ((a) * (b))`. I didn't do this in SUM for smplicity.

Answer (score 1):

"Macro defines" merely indicate how they are specified (with #define directives), while "Macro" is the function or expression that is defined.

There is little difference between them aside from semantics, however.